# In mapbox, how to add a layer below another layer?

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox

I want to dynamically (for example, when a button is clicked) add a layer **below** a GeoJSON layer in mapbox. How do I do that?

Thank you.

Edit: The layer to be added below a GeoJSON layer is a heat map layer: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat. Problem hasn't been solved. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the type of layer you're adding, but the general concept is `z-index`, which tells Leaflet how to sort its layers: [setZIndex()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-setzindex) is a start for tile layers, and [zIndexOffset](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setzindexoffset) for markers.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the type of layer I use: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat. Can you give me some suggestions?